# Cannot serve Express + React application on port 80

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, vps, plesk

I have my React (compiled) + Express (serving static React site) application and I want to serve them on port 80.

The problem is that this is a VPS with Ubuntu and **Plesk Onyx** running several applications as subdomains on `vhosts` on port `80`:

```
server.listen(server.get("PORT"), () => {
  console.log("Server started on", server.get("PORT"));
});
```

I configured `.env` file to listen to port `80` but I get Port already in use when serving Express server file:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::80
>
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1255:14)
>
> at listenInCluster (net.js:1303:12)
>
> at Server.listen (net.js:1391:7)

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Is there any way to set the port as `80` only for this domain?

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a proxy server.

Plesk uses nginx as a proxy server for apache, so you can add another virtual host (server block) that proxies your xpress application.

This question may help you
https://serverfault.com/questions/298392/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-http-https-proxy-server